# How can I import a word table into excel and keep formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am looking to import a word table into excel and keep the formatting; sample text.

> HERE IS SOME SAMPLE TEXT
>
> MORE TEXT
>   MORE TEXT
>
> MORETEXT

The above text is in a single cell in the word table, but when I import into excel it places this text in three separate cells. I need to import the word table (i.e., this word cell) into excel in a single cell.

Not all of my cells/rows are formatted this way,. But some are. So if I could pull in the word table format directly into excel this would be ideal.

Sorry if this is confusing, would be glad to clarify

Thanks

Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files ,*.doc;*.docx;*.docm", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    TableNo = wdDoc.TAbles.Count
    If TableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
        TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
    End If
    With .TAbles(TableNo).Range.Copy
Range("A1").Activate
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"
    End With
End With

Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Before you paste, trying changing to edit mode by using `SendKeys "{F2}"`.

Comment: How are you importing? Copy/Paste? Macro? If a macro, please post the relevant code.

Comment: Code added to original post.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
Sub WordToExcel()
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim x As Integer
Dim strFilename As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim temp As String

Set wdApp = New Word.Application
'initialise counter
x = 1
'search for first file in directory
strFolder = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test\"
strFilename = Dir(strFolder & "*.doc")
'amemd folder name
Do While strFilename <> ""
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(strFolder & strFilename)
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 0) = temp
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 1) = temp
'etc
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 3).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 2) = temp
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 4).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 3) = temp

wdDoc.Close
x = x + 1
strFilename = Dir
Loop
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```